# Firebase error: Blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity

Tags: web-applications, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am getting the error below when testing Firebase authentication

```
We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.
```

How do I fix this without deleting any data?  There has to be a way to enable development/testing this stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You're seeing this error because of sending too many auth requests from or using one IP address for a given period of time. Firebase auth requests are limited for security purposes.

In order to avoid this error in the future, I'd suggest you to throttle or put delays on your authentication requests.

The penalty or blockage will be lifted eventually, or contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) if not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: does this count for getting tokens for FCM? Do you maybe have a link to explain the specifics of the limitations of the auth requests? eg. exactly how many requests /min? Is it maybe per device and not IP?

Comment: hey mate. you can reach out to the [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) regarding this question.

Answer (score 5):

I went into firebase > Authentication > sign-in method > google and added my client id to the whitelist.

Comment: I also went into chrome dev tools > application > and cleared all storage stuff.

Comment: For anyone using the email/password provider, the whitelist (safe list) option is not available.  It seems to be available for Google Auth provider, only.