# Angular + Firebase: Can't resend verification email

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

In my registration process (in my angular web app), I send to the user a verification email, and it works (handled manually using alternative action url).
but when I try to **resend** verification email using:

```
if (user && !user.emailVerified) {
    return user.sendEmailVerification();
}
```

when user is the object that received from: `this.auth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {...});`

I always get:

```
t {code: "auth/too-many-requests", message: "We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.", a: null}
```

and it doesn't matter when I did it or from which device or which IP.
it always happened.

**Important note**: all the other authentication methods working without any problem (even if I call them dozens of times in a row).

Comment: Have you tried to delete the user and retest?
Are you using the free version?

Comment: Yes I have tried it may times. and yes I'm using the free version and everything works besides this small and side feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651582/1930348

Comment: I already tried and it's not fixed my issue. as I said, everything works except this method.