# Firebase Phone Verification verifyPhoneNumber() deprecated + Application Crashed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, deprecated

Getting error after upgrading **Firebase Auth (20.0.0)** dependency for Phone Authentication, **PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber()**

**Dependency:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:92)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.onPostExecute(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:88)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent$Builder"
```

Can anyone explain what should I change for new dependency? What are the new steps?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is what I did to remove the Error:

I referred [firebase phone auth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone) and made the necessary changes:

Replace this:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber, //phone number to be verified
            60, // validity of the OTP
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            (Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallBack // onVerificationStateChangedCallback
    );
```

With this

```
PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                    .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallBack)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

Also, add this to your app/gradle file dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

This will help firebase to open the browser for reCAPTCHA verification.

Hope this works!

Comment: What is the use of `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'` The reCAPTCHA thing will be done by Firebase itself?

Comment: If we are using a phone with no Google Play Services OR an Emulator, Firebase will use reCAPTCHA for phone verification. 
The reCAPTCHA will open in the browser. So, to allow the app to open the browser, we need to add this dependency.

Comment: @JaineelMamtora for me, its opening browser every time I login.. What to do?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Are you using debug apk or release?

Comment: @JaineelMamtora I was using debug apk, (it's the one available under 'build' section right?).

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Okay, so if you are using debug apk, most probably the app will open the browser for verification. If you are using release apk, it will directly send the OTP provided you have added your fingerprints (SHA1 and/or SHA256) in the firebase console. I suggest, use KeyStore Explorer for generating the Keystore and add the Fingerprint generated to the Firebase console.

Comment: @JaineelMamtora Thanks. But keystore can be generated from android studio itself, RHS Gradle menu > Tasks > android > signingReport

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I agree. But when I generated fingerprints from Gradle and tried running the release apk, I was getting an error saying: 'app is not authorized to use firebase authentication'. The error was solved when I generated fingerprints from KeyStore Explorer.

Comment: @JaineelMamtora Fine.. I will remeber this point when I will be generating my keystore. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I was able to read the verification SmsCode in the previous code, but in this new code I am getting the SmsCode but unable to read it and it doesn't show in the log also. could anyone please help me to read the sms code?

Answer (score 16):

Finally, I got solutions with the help of [Alex Mamo's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608740/1318946) and [This Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification)

The steps which I followed:

1. Update new dependency `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'`
2. Update new code:

   **For send OTP:**

   ```
   PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
        PhoneAuthOptions
                .newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
                .setActivity(this)
                .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                .build());
   ```

   **For Resend OTP**

   ```
   PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
            PhoneAuthOptions
                    .newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
                    .setActivity(this)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                    .setForceResendingToken(token)
                    .build());
   ```

   Still, you will get an error as below:

> [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown
> status code: 17028 A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching
> SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that
> this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the
> Firebase Console.

3. You need to copy **SHA-256** from your Keystore or JKS file and add [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/general/) in **SHA Certificate fingerprints:**

   [image]
4. Finally, You did it.

   There is no need for a reCAPTCHA verification.

Thank you.

Comment: I did all the above steps. But its still opening the browser in my mobile. :(

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64614349/1318946

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB You need to enable "Android Device Verification" . You can see  steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248293/9942608

Answer (score 5):

In new Firebase auth version,they've made major changes like Recaptcha for human verification.it needs browser to verify so,Add below depen.and read about changes [refer me](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

```
 implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

Comment: adding  --> implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0' helped from crashing

Answer (score 5):

In new Firebase auth version,they've made major changes like Recaptcha , SafetyNet for human verification. I have faced the same issue by adding

**implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0**

it solved my problem but user experience was not good firebase was opening browser to verify Recaptcha and that was looking odd in app flow.

Firebase Quote "**The reCAPTCHA flow will only be triggered when SafetyNet is unavailable or your device does not pass suspicion checks. Nonetheless, you should ensure that both scenarios are working correctly.**"
So to enable SafetyNet  follow below steps or you can also visit
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth  for info

1. Update auth dependency implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
2. To start PhoneNumber Verification

```html
PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)   // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)    // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks) 
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

3. Go to google cloud console, select your project.
4. Click on the navigation menu and select APis & services and then select Dashboard.
5. Click on enable api and services and enable API "
   Android Device Verification".
6. Add SHA-1 and SHA 256 in firebase project settings.(debug and release both)
7. Download and replace the latest google-services.json file in your project.
8. Test your app again on real device.

Comment: Have you implemented it?

Comment: @PratikButani yes

Comment: This is the only solution which worked perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

As it is specified in the official documentation of [verifyPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber, long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Activity activity, PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#verifyPhoneNumber(java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks)) method:

> This method is deprecated in favor of [verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneAuthOptions)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#verifyPhoneNumber(com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions))

So from now on, to verify a phone number we'll need to call this method and pass a `PhoneAuthOptions` object as an argument. In my opinion, this is some kind of similar to [updateProfile(UserProfileChangeRequest request)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updateProfile(com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest)), where we should pass a `PhoneAuthOptions` object as an argument.

Comment: I am getting `[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode are blocked.`

Comment: First of all, are you sure you are using the correct number? If yes, then most likely it's because the Authentication Service has blocked the service that sends verifications codes. If this error persists, maybe you should contact Firebase tea. However, there are some interesting answers [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=SMS+verification+code+request+failed%3A+unknown+status+code%3A+17499).

Comment: The got solution, [On this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key/) I have *restrict key* that I have changed now to *Don't restrict key*

Comment: Good to hear that ;)

Comment: @AlexMamo I have done all the steps above, mentioned in Pratik's answer, but still it is opening browser before sending otp. What else I have to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Just Replace your previous code with following code:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
 PhoneAuthOptions
         .newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
         .setActivity(this)
         .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
         .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         .setCallbacks(mCallBack)
         .build());
```

**Note:-**  Firebase OTP only works on Real Device. Not working on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

In new Firebase auth version,they've made major changes like Recaptcha for human verification.it needs browser to verify so,Add below depen.and read about changes refer me

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

Update : If you want to avoid human verification, you need to enable safety net in google cloud console for your firebase project refer this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have added SHA 256 in firebase console and its solved.

Thanks @HimanshiThakur (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248293/10787285)