# Firebase Phone Authentication : You cannot require SMS validation without setting a multi-factor session

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am doing Phone Authentication using **Firebase Auth.** As per the new dependency of **Firebase Auth**, `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber()` is deprecated.

I have implemented a new one which is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64608740/1318946)

My Code:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                PhoneAuthOptions
                        .newBuilder(FirebaseAuth.getInstance())
                        .setActivity(this)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)
                        .build());
```

Here when I add [`requireSmsValidation`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#requiresmsvalidation), It's giving me an error **require SMS validation without setting a multi-factor session.**

Can anyone help me to **setMultiFactorSession**? I want to instantly verify without needing to send or enter a verification code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the method `#requireSmsValidation()` is to skip over instant validation. That method is only available for Multi-Factor Authentication flows as part of [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs). It actually does the opposite of what you want - you should leave that method alone. However, most of your users will still need to receive and input the SMS code that is sent to them - there's no getting around that part of the flow.