# How to solve deprecated error in android with some methods?

Tags: android

**error code**

```
private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            (Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallbacks);
```

**in this in logcat its showing that getInstance() is deprecated**

Answer (score 0):

For example you can type in Google something like - `phoneauthprovider.getinstance() deprecated` and the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608484/firebase-phone-verification-verifyphonenumber-deprecated-application-crashed) will possibly solve the problem. As you can see you use similar code to another SO question. Anyway you will need to replace your code with:

```
PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                    .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .setCallbacks(mCallBack)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .build();
    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```

and check [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone)

Comment: i tryed this but this also not working after putting this its showing mare new errors

Comment: it is showing 29 errors cannot resolve symbol 'PhoneAuthOptions' and many more like this

Comment: did you add this dependency - `implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'` ?

Comment: no, is there any solution with the same code