# Invalid SafetyNetToken in firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented firebase phone verification successfully following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248293/8989121). Few OTP verification was successful but after some time I got this error

```
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 An invalid safety_net_token was passed.

This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ An invalid safety_net_token was passed ]
```

I searched a lot about invalid SafetyNet token but can't find any useful link. I am getting OTP via reCAPTCHA verification but only having issue with SafetyNet. I also tried using new `SHA 1` keys and latest `google-services.json`. That also didn't work

NOTE: I have two apps in the `google-services.json` due to debug suffix in `build.gradle`

```
debug {
    applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an outage in SafetyNet earlier today, which affected Firebase App Check and Firebase Authentication. The issue has now been resolved, and you can see this [status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/dkXbnYKe9fJ13dLGiHZk) for details.