# We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity - Firebase on flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I published [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tgnt.flutteringflags) on google play store and it is using firebase phone authentication and firestore. At first some of my friends downloaded and used the app without problems, but later some new users complained about the error message on the below screenshot.

[image]

Since I am not testing on those phone, I could not find a solution for this problem yet. I searched [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601942/firebase-3-we-have-blocked-all-requests-from-this-device-due-to-unusual-activi) and many on the Internet but those questions are about testing. As these messages get remote users who downloaded the app from google play, I could not find the solution for my situation yet. Please can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: It seems like firebase blocks a device if it is sending too many requests to get an SMS verification (I believe it caps at 5 SMS every 4 hours), Are you asking for an SMS every time the user logs in?

Comment: no several first time users reported this. and only need to login once..

Comment: You may be hitting a quota limit. Have you been able to find any meaningful entries regarding this in your logs? Are you using verification emails? I suggest [testing with fictional phone numbers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

After researching for sometime and getting advices from a friend I changed my Firebase Spark Plan (free) to Blaze Plan (Pay as you go) and the problem solved.